# Wordpress Functions.php filter get_metadata is always empty

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I have a post and I need to process some of the meta data attached to that post.

I am struggling to get the post meta when calling get_metadata('post',53 ) where 53 is the specific postid I need.

The write_log function outputs to my debug log and the return value is always empty.

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_indexer_row_data', function( $rows, $params ) {
        if ( 'company_categories' == $params['facet']['name'] ) {
                        write_log($params); //params contains correct values
                        $defaults = $params['defaults'];
                      $post_id = (int) $defaults['post_id'];
                        $post = get_post($post_id);
                        $postType = $post->post_type;
                        write_log($postType." - ".$post_id); //postType and post_id contains correct values

                        //global $post;
                        if($postType == 'upt_user'){
                            $meta = get_metadata('post',$post_id );
                            write_log($meta); //meta is empty when using both $post_id variable and actual id value '53'
                        }
                    }

            return $rows;
}, 999, 2 );
```

If I add the exact same code to a php template it returns the metadata without issue.
e.g.

```
$meta = get_metadata('post',53 );
```

I actually started with the get_post_meta function but I'm currently using get_metadata to simplify and rule out any issues with misusing the get_post_meta function and parameters.

Any suggestions of how to resolve please?

Comment: try `wp_reset_query();`  before  `$meta = get_metadata('post',$post_id );`

Comment: @Noman why would you reset the query inside of a filter?

Comment: Try `get_metadata('upt_user',$post_id );` When you `write_log( $postType . " - " $post_id)`, what are you getting for `$postType`? It seems you are checking if the post type is `upt_user` but then trying to get the meta from `post` using the `upt_user` post id.